# MySQLTest Error when trying to connect C# to MySql

Tags: c#, mysql

I am not able to find this answer anywhere. I'm just trying to connect a basic console app to a database, it's not working, throwing an exception. I've checked all variables to make sure it's correct. Getting `MySQLTest Error: 0 : SSL Connection error. Exception thrown: 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' in MySql.Data.dll`
For some reason.

```
string connStr = "server=127.0.0.1;user=root;database=secretplace;port=3307;password=12345";
using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr))
{
    try
    {

        conn.Open();
    }
    catch (MySqlException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }

    conn.Close();
    Console.WriteLine("Connection Closed. Press any key to exit...");
    Console.Read();
}
```

This is the only code that I have in main, It's not getting past the Open() statement, just throwing an exception.

I am saying `using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;` up top.

Comment: without seeing a connectio string, it is mpossible to say if it is correct,

Comment: My bad, didn't realize that it didn't show up in the question.

Comment: isn't mysql default port 3306?

Comment: Yes, but my db is on port 3307 @Squirrel.98

Comment: try adding this `SSL Mode=Required`. `"server=127.0.0.1;user=root;database=secretplace;port=3307;password=12345;SSL Mode=Required"`

Comment: @Squirrel.98 It now says ```MySQLTest Error: 0 : The host 127.0.0.1 does not support SSL connections.
Exception thrown: 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException' in MySql.Data.dll```

Comment: Try `SslMode=none` not `required`

Comment: @Squirrel.98 Did you mean `SSL Mode=None`

Comment: @Squirrel.98 The SSL Mode = None worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `SslMode=none` as mentioned in the comments.